# Is there a hotel in Paris with a grand piano "en suite"?

Tags: hotels, paris

Does anybody know a  hotel in Paris with a grand piano in the room/suite ?

Comment: Romantic marriage invitation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Hôtel de Crillon, suite Bernstein (fr)](http://blog.vinivi.com/2011/03/16/une-nuit-a-l%e2%80%99hotel-de-crillon/).

[image: Hôtel de Crillon, suite Bernstein]

(image from [www.drivingadelorean.com](http://www.drivingadelorean.com/hotel-de-crillon-paris-fashion-week.html/crillon03))

Have a nice stay!

Comment: As of summer 2015, the hotel is [closed for renovation](http://www.crillon.com/).